# Transaction Action with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, actioncontroller

I have a complex action inside controller that performs several update queries to the database.

How can I make this action *acts like transaction* without any structural refactoring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyModel.transaction do
  begin
    @model.update_stuff
    @sub_model.update_stuff
    @sub_sub_model.update_stuff
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid # or whatever 
    # rollback is automatic, but if you want to do something additional, 
    # add it here
  end
end
```

Here are [the docs for the transaction method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 5):

It's posible to make all actions in controller transactional at once with:

```
around_filter :transactional

def transactional
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    yield
  end
end
```

Comment: Aspect-oriented programming. Is there nothing Ruby can't do? (Besides work on Windows.)